# Data cleaning - member id with different products

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
MEMBER_ID   Prod_Aug    Purchase Date   Prod_Sept   Purchase Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
10002       1840357     2017-08-16      1840357     2017-09-21 12:20:41.000000
10002       1840357     2017-08-16      1840355     2017-09-21 12:20:40.000000
10004       516430      2017-08-16      516430      
10004       516430      2017-08-16      524909      2017-09-15 17:34:25.000000
10018       1106537     2017-08-16      1106537     2017-09-21 08:06:06.000000
10018       1106537     2017-08-16      1115994     2017-09-21 08:06:06.000000
10019       1123349     2017-08-16      1128221     2017-09-08 20:46:28.000000
```

I want the result to look like the following:

```
MEMBER_ID   Prod_Aug    Purchase Date  Prod_Sept    Purchase Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10002       1840357     2017-08-16     1840357      2017-09-21 12:20:41.000000
10004       516430      2017-08-16     524909       2017-09-15 17:34:25.000000
10019       1123349     2017-08-16     1128221      2017-09-08 20:46:28.000000
10021       704290      2017-08-16     Null         Null
```

- Return 1840357 because although there are purchase dates for both products, he purchased product 1840357 as his "first" purchase in August, and persisted to purchase 1840357 in September
- Return 524909 because even though 516430 was also in the inventory, he only purchased 524909
- Return 1128221 because although neither prod#2s were purchased in the first cycle (August), he purchased one similar product named 1128221 over 1127912
- Return 'null; because he did not make any purchase in September

I have access to SQL / Teradata as well, so if writing out a code is easier, please feel free to help me that way. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some example data for each of your conditions and the expected output? Right now, there's only one Updated Date for a row, so it applies to both Prod1 and Prod2. So your 2nd example doesn't make sense. We need a little bit clearer of an example of what you're working with and what you expect.

Comment: Edited - thank you!

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward implementation of a Query in SQL grouping on a couple of fields and doing some Max or Min's on the other fields. Why is this tagged as Excel? What have you done so far and what errors is preventing you from running your code? Remember that SO is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get targeted advice on coding issues.

Comment: I can't follow your logic, but it seems to be a simple `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY some logic based on a CASE to define the ordering rules)  = 1`.